# Swift - Pass base64EncodedString to ASP.NET API

Tags: ios, swift

I am converting UIImages to base64EncodedString like so:

```
let imageData:Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)!

let imageStr = imageData.base64EncodedString()
```

and I am trying to pass it over to ASP.NET API Controller like so:

```
func postLandGradingImages(_ cellHolder: Array<ImagesData>, completion: @escaping (_ result: String) -> Void)
    {

        //Define Array of Dictionary

        var jsonArrayOfDictionaries = [[AnyHashable: Any]]()

        //For each item in the cellHolder

        for i in 0..<cellHolder.count {

            //Define Dictionary for grading data

            var jsonDict = [AnyHashable: Any]()

            //Set Lot

            jsonDict["jobNo"] = cellHolder[i].jobNo

            //Set Image

            jsonDict["imageBytes"] = cellHolder[i].ImageBytes

            //Add Dictionary to Array of Dictionary

            jsonArrayOfDictionaries.append(jsonDict)

            //Clear Dictionary

            jsonDict = [AnyHashable: Any]()

        }

        //Convert Array of Dictionary to JSON Data

        let jsonData: Data? = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonArrayOfDictionaries, options: .prettyPrinted)

        //Define our URL with the credentials

        let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: webservice + "PostGradingImages");

        //Assign Username

        urlComponents?.user = appDelegate.username;

        //Assign Password

        urlComponents?.password = appDelegate.password;

        //Define our URL String

        let url = urlComponents?.url;

        //Define URL Request

        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        //Set Header Values for request

        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        //Set Header Values for request

        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        //Set Request Method to POST

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        //Set Request Body to JSON Data

        request.httpBody = jsonData

        let returnedData = String()

        //Start out URL Session to post data

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) in

            //If there is an error return false.

            if(error != nil){

                //return false

                completion(returnedData)

            }else{

                //Get the response

                let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)

                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({

                    //return true

                    completion(responseString!)

                })

            }

        }).resume()
    }
```

The problem is, my .NET code does not like my base64EncodedString, I get this error from .NET:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What I am trying to accomplish is sending the base64EncodedString from the UIImage to .NET so I can convert it to bytes so I can save it. But my .NET is not accepting my base64EncodedString....what Am I doing wrong?

Comment: can't your .Net save base64 image, why you convert to byte

Comment: Im trying to save the byte array to an sql database

Comment: can't you save base 64 as string inside Sql Databse